# Python CGI ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'

Tags: python, apache, datetime, cgi, aes

My code consists of an aesencrypt, aesdecrypt, aespad, aesunpad, cookiegenerate, cookieverify, tokengenerated, tokenverified, and expiredtime functions as follows:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
from datetime import datetime as dtime
from http import cookies as Cookie

# time until token expiration in seconds
ExpirationTime = 3600
# encryption parameters
BlockSize = 16

# aes encryption function
def aesencrypt(data, passphrase):
    iv = Random.new().read(BlockSize)
    cipher = AES.new(passphrase, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    encrypted = base64.b64encode(iv+cipher.encrypt(aespad(data)))
    return encrypted
# aes decryption function
def aesdecrypt(encrypted, passphrase):
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encrypted)
    iv = decoded[:BlockSize]
    cipher = AES.new(passphrase, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    decrypted = aesunpad(cipher.decrypt(decoded[BlockSize:]))
    return decrypted
# aes pad function
def aespad(data):
    length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
    data += bytes([length])*length
    return data
# aes unpad function
def aesunpad(data):
    data = data[:-data[-1]]
    return data
# expiration check helper function
def expiredtime(ttime, exptime):
    now = dtime.utcnow()
    then = dtime.strptime(ttime, "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    diff = (now - then).total_seconds()
    if diff > exptime:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# aes token generator
def tokengenerated(thekey):
    return aesencrypt(dtime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").encode('utf-8'), thekey)

# aes token verifier
def tokenverified(thetoken, thekey):
    decrypted = aesdecrypt(thetoken, thekey)
    if expiredtime(decrypted.decode('utf-8'), ExpirationTime):
        return False
    else:
        return True

# cookie generation function
def cookiegenerate(thekey, subid):
    cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    cookie['session'] = tokengenerated(thekey)
    cookie["session"]['domain'] = "MYSERVER"
    cookie["session"]['path'] = '/'
    cookie['session']['expires'] = 'expires in %s seconds' % (ExpirationTime)
    cookie['user_id'] = aesencrypt(str(subid).encode('utf-8'), thekey)
    return cookie.output()

# cookie verification function
def cookieverify(acookie, thekey):
    return tokenverified(acookie['session'].value, thekey)
```

When my code that is using these functions hits 'if cookieverify(cookie, akey):' it returns the following error:

> [Thu Aug 10 14:40:35.099480 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774] [client
>   ME:51769] AH01215:   File "/var/www/html/cgi-bin/authdefs.py", line
>   63, in tokenverified: /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer:
>   MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10 14:40:35.099493 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774]
>   [client ME:51769] AH01215:     if
>   expiredtime(decrypted.decode('utf-8'), ExpirationTime)::
>   /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10
>   14:40:35.099518 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774] [client ME:51769]
>   AH01215:   File "/var/www/html/cgi-bin/authdefs.py", line 49, in
>   expiredtime: /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER [Thu
>   Aug 10 14:40:35.099528 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774] [client ME:51769]
>   AH01215:     then = dtime.strptime(ttime, "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"):
>   /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10
>   14:40:35.099545 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774] [client ME:51769]
>   AH01215:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in
>   _strptime_datetime: /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10 14:40:35.099560 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774]
>   [client ME:51769] AH01215:     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string,
>   format): /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug
>   10 14:40:35.099573 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774] [client ME:51769]
>   AH01215:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in
>   _strptime: /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10 14:40:35.099579 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9774] [client ME:51769]
>   AH01215:     (data_string, format)): /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py,
>   referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10 14:40:35.099591 2017] [cgi:error] [pid
>   9774] [client ME:51769] AH01215: ValueError: time data '' does not
>   match format '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S': /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py,
>   referer: MYSERVER [Thu Aug 10 14:40:35.116910 2017] [cgi:error] [pid
>   9774] [client ME:51769] End of script output before headers:
>   newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER

I can verify that I am storing a cookie and can retrieve it using a short test script as well as that my encryption and decryption functions are working as expected, but for some reason the datetime string that I'm getting back from the client's cookie after decrypting it gives me a ValueError.

Anyone know what's going on? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I added some lines to save the cookie[session].value to a file and got: "NameError: name 'session' is not defined: /var/www/html/cgi-bin/newsite.py, referer: MYSERVER" despite running cookiegenerate() on the previous page and seeing the cookie via EditThisCookie (value is "b'leP3KVY5tBI9HlwUjWvouNBGasECueng/1T7fu5TPRw='") and cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"]) in the script that's giving me problems.

Comment: can you post what the value of decrypted.decode('utf-8') is in the tokenverified function? The error is complaining that the string you are trying to convert to a datetime object does not match the pattern you specified ("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

Comment: 20170810-151008

Comment: your log indicates that the value of decrypted.decode('utf-8') is an empty string. Try adding a print statement to print the value of decrypted.decode('utf-8') before you execute the if expired time line

Comment: I get an empty string and I understood that I was getting an empty string. I was wondering why I'm getting an empty string despite storing a cookie that contains an encrypted time stamp and the user_id. I have used the EditThisCookie Chrome Extension and can confirm that the cookie is as it should be. Something is going wrong when retrieving the token from the cookie.

Comment: The actual content of the cookie is stored on my machine as "b'TtExLHzNLkBC3wpZ+Q0bjrL7vVumMZlycWdpGWRF/nA='".